# Html.DropDownListFor will ignore ViewBag values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I have the following action method:-

```
 public ActionResult AdvanceSearch(string AssetTypeName) 

        {
            ViewBag.Techtypes = repository.GetAllTechnologyType().ToList();
            ViewBag.AssetID = repository.GetTechnologyTypeID(AssetTypeName);                

            return View();
        }
```

which will call the folloiwng view :-
//code goes here

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.AssetTypeID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TechnologyType>)ViewBag.Techtypes).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" :option.Name), 
        Value = option.AssetTypeID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (option.AssetTypeID == ViewBag.AssetID)
    }), "All")
```

//code goes here

but the drop down will always show the default value"All" , instead of selecting the item that match the viewBag value `option.AssetTypeID == ViewBag.AssetID`. baring in ming that the ViewBag will have the correct value. can anyone adice what might be the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: just wondering whether the below solution works for you? Or you still having the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your condition is wrong. Try this. Check the 'Selected' property.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AssetTypeID, ((IEnumerable<TechnologyType>)ViewBag.Techtypes).Select(option => new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name),
               Value = option.AssetTypeID.ToString(),
               Selected = (option.AssetTypeID == (int)ViewBag.AssetID)
           }), "All")
```